# CoreData in Swift throws One-to-Many error

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many

I have a project using CoreData that uses a schema that has been stable for some time.

in an area that I have been modifying, an entity called `Answer` looks like this:

[image]

So, only a container for relationships. Until recently, the `answeredBy` relationship was allowed multiple `Member`s to answer a given question. But now, instead, only one `Member` provides an answer. However, a circumstance can arise where two `Member`s answer as a team. In this case, two `Answer`s are generated at the same time.

So, a `Member` has many `Answer`s where they are the unique `answerer`, but `Answer`s have only one `Member` as `answeredBy`.

[image]

This kind on one-to-many seems totally unproblematic, but Swift refuses to compile now, with this error:

```
VideoMentor/AppDelegate.swift:58: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." UserInfo={sourceModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000021208c0>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Answer = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000035106e0>) name Answer, managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier Answer, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), 
properties {\n    answeredBy = \"(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x600003311a40>), name answeredBy, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Answer, renamingIdentifier answeredBy, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, destination entity Member, inverseRelationship answerer, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1\";\n    
challenge = \"(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x6000033110e0>), name challenge, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Answer, renamingIdentifier challenge, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, destination entity Challenge, inverseRelationship answer, minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1\";\n    
team = \"(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x600003311900>), name team, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Answer, renamingIdentifier team, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, destination entity Team, inverseRelationship answers, minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1\";\n 
   videos = \"(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x6000033115e0>), name videos, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Answer, renamingIdentifier videos, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, destination entity Video, inverseRelationship teamAnswer, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 2\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n        (\n        challenge,\n        team\n    )\n)";
```

I am confused. Have checked code for any inappropriate calls to relationships, haven't found any, and no errors are thrown in that direction I've found.

I kind of loathe the wearing oven mitts feeling of working with CoreData, but I'm stuck with it. Any insights?

Comment: This is not a compilation error but a runtime error. The error occurs when the app starts and tries to update the persistent store but fails, "… migration failed". You need to provide instructions how to migrate from the old to the new core data model.

Comment: "You need to provide instructions how to migrate from the old to the new core data mode" My impression was that CD auto migrates, and that a new DB would be generated. How do I provide such instructions? I thought that's the point of the CoreData configuration screen.

Comment: easiest thing was to delete he .sql file: everything worked fine after that.

Comment: When you are still in the development phase and has no data you need to keep then throwing away the database file and let core data build a new one is always the most practical solution. As for migration, core data can only do simple straightforward migrations automatically for simple migrations like when you add an optional property or add a property with a default value but here you wanted to change the type of the relationship and then you need to specify how the existing data should be handled. Since this has been resolved I suggest you delete the question.